# Validate data input for range 1.2-4.8 using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, validation

I need a regular expression which validates user input in the range between 1.2 to 4.8. Both 1.2 and 4.8 are inclusive with the range. ALSO inputs without decimals such as 2,3 and 4 are valid and so are 2.0,3.0 and 4.0.

Comment: But why do you need regex for this?

Comment: simply check the value. `val>=1.2 && val<=4.8`

Comment: I want to use regex so that my program can catch all possible errors of invalid data entry including letters. Also using regex to validate data input is a requirement for my task

Comment: I'm fairly certain that Java will the appropriate error if a letter is scanned instead of a number so you won't **need** regex for that.

Comment: This looks a lot like a "please do my homework" question from a student. In this case, I'd like to remind others that offering a ready-to-use solution won't help the student. If not, then it's a bad question anyway, not showing any previous effort. Either way, -1 from me, sorry. If I could, I would add another -1 for the bad google skills (I'm sure you could easily find the answer with some proper search) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex to validate the number ranges from 1.2 to 4.8,

```
^(?:1\.[2-9]|[2-3]\.[0-9]|4\.[0-8]|2|3|4)$
```

Java regex would be,

```
"^(?:1\\.[2-9]|[2-3]\\.[0-9]|4\\.[0-8]|2|3|4)$"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pZ7bC3/1)

Comment: Just to point it out, this will only work for numbers with one number after the decimal point. Hopefully it will work for OP

Comment: yep. that's what op said.